# Installing Compass

Tags: ruby, haml, compass-sass

Once again, having trouble installing Compass, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521087/installing-compass-following-the-compass-primer) only different.

My versions and error:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS \n \l
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
$ compass -v
Compass 0.8.17 [2465bab]
Copyright (c) 2008-2009 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
$ haml -v
Haml/Sass 3.0.18 (Classy Cassidy)
$ compass -w --trace
NoMethodError on line 18 of /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/stylesheet_updating.rb: undefined method `dependency_updated?' for Sass::Plugin:Module
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/compiler.rb:39:in `out_of_date?'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/compiler.rb:38:in `each'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/compiler.rb:38:in `out_of_date?'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:52:in `recompile'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:18:in `perform'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:15:in `execute'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/exec.rb:242:in `do_command'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/exec.rb:57:in `perform!'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/lib/compass/exec.rb:40:in `run!'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/chriseppstein-compass-0.8.17/bin/compass:8
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/compass:19:in `load'
  /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/compass:19
```

I looked at stylesheet_updating.rb and it's some monkey patch esoterica I don't know how to debug.

The Compass primer I found reference to is from 2008, which doesn't seem helpful.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

...fired up the command line and launched the synaptic with “sudo synaptic”, put in my password and ran a search for “libcompass-ruby”. The search came up with two files: libcompass-ruby and libcompass-ruby1.8 These files were installed. I quickly right clicked and selected “Mark for Complete Removal” and removed them by clicking the “Apply” button. I returned to my project and tried running “compass —watch” and this time it worked. http://mawuli.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/how-i-troubleshooted-my-compass-sass-rubygem-installation…/

Answer (score 0):

I had installed with

```
$ sudo gem install chriseppstein-compass
```

Apparently that gets me mixed-up versions.

Did:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall chriseppstein-compass
$ sudo gem install compass
```

and it is now running.